# How to show other view from same view class?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rap

I need to open multiple view from a same view class with different data.

For more detail. I have TreeViewer with six TreeParent. Now, when I select one parent my application will show a view and if I click other one that will not show anymore. Now I want show view for each tree item I clicked.

Any suggestion?

My current code:

```
viewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

        @Override
        public void selectionChanged(SelectionChangedEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ITreeSelection iTreeSelection = (ITreeSelection) viewer
                    .getSelection();
            Object firstElement = iTreeSelection.getFirstElement();
            try {
                IWorkbenchWindow iWorkbenchWindow = PlatformUI
                        .getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
                View.setTree(firstElement);
                iWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage().showView(View.ID);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
    });`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open multiple copies of the same view by using a 'secondary id' to distinguish the views. You the alternative version of `showView` for this:

```
IWorkbenchPage activePage = iWorkbenchWindow.getActivePage();

activePage.showView(View.ID, secondaryId, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);
```

where `secondaryId` is a string that identifies the particular instance of the view.